# Vim cursor pauses when typing backslash

Tags: vim, escape-characters

I use vim as my primary text editor, and one (seemingly) useless attribute is that when I type the `\` character, the cursor doesn't move for a moment or until I type another character.

Functionally, it presents no issue, since it doesn't cause the end result to change. However, I have a bit of OCD, and the fact that `\` is treated like a special character and freezes the cursor for that moment really irritates me. Is there a way to turn that feature off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have insert mode mappings. This is probably from some plugin you installed or your vimrc. The mapping probably used `<leader>` as the start of the mapping.

To find the mappings use `verbose imap \`. This will display all the insert mode mappings that start with `\` and where the setting was set.

To stop this you can either remove the mappings (recommended) or change `timeoutlen` to something shorter. (However this could make it harder to type your multi key mappings in normal mode). `timeoutlen` is the time it takes for vim to decide that you actually want the character instead of the start of some mapping. This is why there is a pause.